# Ng Select prevent input height to increase multiple select | display "..." in the end

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

How to prevent ngselect input (mulitple=true) height from increasing and showing all the selected chips rather display "..."
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks more of a css fix:

```
.itemToShowElipsis {
    height: 40px; /* as per your requirement */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* this property will show ... */
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.itemToShowElipsis {
  height: 40px;
  /* as per your requirement */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  /* this property will show ... */
}
```

```html
<div class="itemToShowElipsis">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</div>
```